# Change background color of parent menu only if it has submenu wrapped inside div container

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a mega menu which show submenus wrapped inside div along with brief text and image. Not all parent menu has sub menu as shown in the example.

On hover i want to change `background-color` for only those parent menu items which have sub menus.

So in my example only ***parent one, parent two, parent three*** and ***parent four*** will have background color as  `background-color:#e5e5e5` for others i don't need background color as they don't have sub menu items.

I tried to change it using pseudo column but i'm unable to target it right may be i am doing something wrong.

some of the CSS which i tried

```
.nav>li a:hover:has (>div)
    {
       background-color:red !important;
      font-weight:bold !important;
    }
    .nav>li:has(>div)
    {
       background-color:red !important;
      font-weight:bold !important;
    }
    .nav>li:has(> a.active){
       background-color:red !important;
      font-weight:bold !important;
    }
```

complete fiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/uv1kj1oh/6/)

I have already tried few answer which are similar to my qustion on stackoverflow but they dont seem to be working.

I want to do it using pure css solution not jQuery as it is possible with jQuery but i want to avoid jQuery.

Comment: Your pure CSS attempts don't work because they're not supported (and the first one is invalid thanks to the seemingly sloppily-written code). Where on Stack Overflow did you find an answer suggesting that they work today?

Comment: Is there a way i can do it with pseudo column. out of frustration i was trying different thing to see if it might work as i was not able to find similar example.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to target the parent menus with submenus:

```
.nav li:nth-child(2):hover > a { background-color: aqua; }
.nav li:nth-child(3):hover > a { background-color: aqua; }
.nav li:nth-child(4):hover > a { background-color: aqua; }
.nav li:nth-child(5):hover > a { background-color: aqua; }
```

Here's how to target the submenus:

```
.nav li:nth-child(2):hover .dropdown { background-color: lightgreen; }
.nav li:nth-child(3):hover .dropdown { background-color: yellow; }
.nav li:nth-child(4):hover .dropdown { background-color: lightblue; }
.nav li:nth-child(5):hover .dropdown { background-color: lawngreen; }
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/uv1kj1oh/13/)

Comment: This is not dynamic in nature suppose if i add new parent menu or remove parent menu items then i have to change the css also. this can be done with one or two lines of jQuery code that wont need to be changed even if we add or remove parent menu. Pardon me if i got your concept wrong

Comment: I understand. Your question didn't mention that menu items would be added and removed, and you prefer not to change CSS once set. I was under the impression the menu was somewhat static. If there's no value in this answer to you, just let me know and I'll delete it.

Comment: I appreciate your reply this might be useful to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" aria-label="Basic example">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">one</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Two</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary">Three</button>
</div>
```

check the above code with **bootstrap**